# War on ads: Stop IE11 from even requesting Javascript files

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, javascript, advertisements

There is a point when enough is enough. And it is now. Ads, vids, pop up, hover, cover, whizz-bang doodle bling and autoplay … I can't stand it any more. With HTML5, this ad crap has become a plight on the Internet, and decisive counter-measures have to be taken.

I'm using IE11 on Windows 7 and 8.1 (no Edge/10 for me, no Firefox, no Chrome, no thanks). You can neutralize Flash by uninstalling or via menu » Security » ActiveX filtering. But there is no way to disable iframes of html5 video in IE11, which are major sources of annoyance.

So I decided to go nuclear and disable Javascript. Whow! A massive improvement! Tons of crap pulled in via ridiculously inefficient pre-alpha Javascript garbage won't be downloaded to your computer any more, and your CPU won't be sent spinning any more, taskmgr will only spike for page loads and spend most of its time peacefully flatlining away.

The war on ads really can be led as a war on (unsolicited) Javascript.

The downside, of course, is that, as *collateral damage*, many sites will lose functionality, so you have to add them to IE's *Trusted Zone* where you still allow Javascript execution. To transfer your list of trusted sites to another machine, dump this key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains
```

To find out what sites you need to allow, use the network tab on the F12 tool.

So I find things are much improved using this simple and efficient nuclear Javascript blocker, but IE still *seems* to be *requesting* Javascript files from sites. (It does request these files when opening the F12 tool.) So, hmm, why download stuff you're not allowed to execute anyway? That doesn't seem to be very smart.

Is there a way, in IE11, to prevent HTTP requests for Javascript files, at least those for URLs ending in `.js`, which is the large majority of Javascript out there, from being executed?

Comment: I voted this question down because you don't seem to actually have a question that is on topic.  You indicate what your problem is, you then proceed to resolve it, but then ask some really broad question that would only lead to a discussion on said topic.  I voted to close for similar reasons.

Comment: Like Ramhound said, this question needs to be a little more concise and address the actual problem you're intending to solve. As it is, it's very broad and will simply lead to discussion rather than a solution.

Comment: You may get better results with something like [Blocking Unwanted Connections with a Hosts File](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm). Other hosts files are available.

Comment: @Ramhound: My question is precise and on topic, not *broad* as you bizarrely claim; looks like you didn't read the title, nor the last paragraph. I fear you do not know the answer because you don't know IE well enough (which is perfectly okay) and hence elect to act against a question that a more knowledgeable user may be able to answer (which is questionable demeanour). As a rule, if you don't have anything useful to contribute, then don't. - @Andrew, HOSTS.TXT won't prevent requests (but yes, it can defeat them to `127.0.0.1`); another problem is it cannot single out Javascript requests.

Comment: So what exactly is this clear ontopic question because I don't see it.  If you make it clear I am more then happy to reverse my vote and retract my close vote.

Comment: Quoting myself, last paragraph: »Is there a way, in IE11, to prevent HTTP requests for Javascript files … from being executed?« - I realize that technically, »yes/no« would constitute a valid answer, but of course the intent is to know *how* it can be done. (Obviously, my question presupposes that the reader know what an HTTP request is, and that they are fired by the browser executable, and that there *might be* a registry config or an API to hook into how requests are fired … but I had taken that for granted.)

Comment: Adblock Plus is available for IE11

Comment: Browser extensions I recommend: Adblock, flashblock, noscript, and maybe ghostery. You can also use the Fiddler program to modify traffic

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples, thank you for these suggestions. I know Fiddler, but it's an extra program to install, and it feels like overkill (and overhead) for a simple requirement like *not requesting JS files*. Flashblock and Noscript are for Mozilla and out of the question here, this is *only* about Microsoft IE. Thanks for suggesting Adblock Plus for IE - didn't know, will try. But so far I really like the JS-less browsing mode, it's troublefree and great for performance. Now let's focus on my **question**, please.

Comment: ABP resolves your problem. If you have another one, ask a new question

Comment: ABP is an extra extension to install. While you think that it "resolves the problem", it does not even answer the question, which is about Microsoft Internet Explorer and HTTP request. … This is getting absurd. Will try StackOverflow directly next time … because a *Super User* seems to be a rare bird around here …

Answer (score 0):

To hook into the request phase, IE provides the [`BeforeNavigate2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326(v=vs.85).aspx), where you can make use of the `Cancel` parameter. However, it is [reported](http://blog.salsitasoft.com/igor-tandetniks-passthrough-app-now-on-github/) (haven't tried it yet) that this hook won't fire for derivative requests (Javascript, CSS, etc). In order to suppress that kind of request, you'd need to follow Igor Tandetnik's Passthrough APP approach referred to in the page I linked to. You'll then find it'll [serialize requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2569878/269126), thus hurting performance; which can be avoided by patching the `vtbl` of the COM object on the HTTP/S protocols as suggested on that page. Which is a rather involved approach. You then end up with a BHO, which is not Bosnia-Herzegovina, but a Browser Helper Object.

While the question clearly fits the SuperUser format, it just so happens that Microsoft has not made this configurable and not even satisfactorily programmable, so the answer is a bit more involved than installing a browser extension …